# Xcode multiple project dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode

My app is complicated, for making my app source code clear, I created multiple projects in workspace. In one project, there is a lot of utils\helpers classes that I want to use in another project. I set the `Search Paths` on `Build Settings` pane so that I can import those utils\helpers files then get snippet when coding. But the problem is: **in fact, those files are not imported into the build path**.

I check the implementation of [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/), found there is a shell script named `Pods-resources.sh` doing some copy stuff. The shell script is complicated and i want to know is there any easy way(settings are better) to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add them into `Compile Sources` in "Build Phases" if you want to use source files in other place

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `Pods-update` first, and then reset the `build path`!